# object relationships and passing object ids to multiple controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, table-relationships

I am in a pickle on the best way to do something and would appreciate some advice.

I have the following models:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :user_id

  validates :name, :presence => true
end

class Planplace < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :plan_id, :planplace

  validates :planplace, :presence => true
end

class Plandate < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :plan_id, :plandate

  validates :plandate, :presence => true
end
```

A plan can have many plandates and planplaces.
I have a contoller for each of these that do a very basic create.

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController

def create
    @plan = Plan.new(params[:plan])
    if @plan.save
        flash[:success] = "Created ..."
    else
        flash[:alert] = "placeplace save error ..."
    end
end   
end

class PlanplacesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @planplace = Planplace.new(params[:planplace])
        if @planplace.save
            flash[:success] = "Created ..."
        else
            flash[:alert] = "placeplace save error ..."
        end
    end
end

class PlandatesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @plandate = Plandate.new(params[:plandate])
        if @plandate.save
            flash[:success] = "Created ..."
        else
            flash[:alert] = "plandate save error ..."
        end
    end
end
```

What I need to do is have one single view that creates a plan and allows several plandates and several planplaces to be saved using that plan.plan_id.

What is the best way of achieving this on a basic level (I will aim at doing ajax calls for saving without reloading but I am far off this, I am still trying to learn).

Do I place this within a single 'new' plan view?. I have played around with a form that uses fields_for to update more that one model within the same form but I would like to get a general idea of the best approach to take here before plodding on.

I know I need to make use of the has_many and belongs_to within the model but I am unsure the best way to do the complete save so the relationship is correct.

Hopefully I have explained this well.
Any suggestions on the best approach is much appreciated.

(please be kind, I have only been learning Rails for a month now)

---Edit ---
I have worked out the model here and how to pass the objects I need. I don't think I asked this question correctly since I was a little confused. Thanks for all who had a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [nested model forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast).

In your case, a plan `has_many :plandates` and `has_many :planplaces`.  Both Plandate and Planplace `belongs_to :plan`. Plandates and Planplaces then need a column for `plan_id:integer`.

Comment: I have added the plan_id to both tables. This is all new to me so trying to get to the right solution not a 'just pulled together but its not the best' solution